# T-SQL: How to avoid string manipulation on this XML?

Tags: sql-server, xml

I need to move a node from one place to another in some XML, but after becoming frustrated, I used string manipulation.

I'm trying to move `<ReaderTypeID>5</ReaderTypeID>` from under `<SCPReplyMessage>` to be under `<SCPReplyMessage><tran>`

The section of code where I take a node from outside tran and move it inside tran became troubling and I had to get it working, so I resorted to a more comfortable (but inefficient) approach: string manipulation.

```
        -- move ReaderTypeID from outside <tran> to be inside <tran>
        DECLARE @rtidXml VARCHAR(100)
        SELECT @rtidXml = CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),@ReplyMessageXml.query('/SCPReplyMessage/ReaderTypeID'))
        DECLARE @st NVARCHAR(max)
        SET @st = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),@tranXml)
        SET @st = REPLACE(@st,'</tran>',@rtidXml + '</tran>')
        SET @tranXml.modify('delete /SCPReplyMessage/ReaderTypeID')
```

I'd like to accomplish the same result without the CONVERT to and from XML.

Thanks!

the function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_mTranAddl (@ReplyMessageXml XML)
returns XML
AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @tranXml XML
        SELECT @tranXml = @ReplyMessageXml.query('/SCPReplyMessage/tran')
        -- Discard extraneous tran elements
        SET @tranXml.modify('delete /tran/ser_num')
        SET @tranXml.modify('delete /tran/time')
        SET @tranXml.modify('delete /tran/sys')
        SET @tranXml.modify('delete /tran/sys_comm')
        -- move ReaderTypeID from outside <tran> to be inside <tran>
        DECLARE @rtidXml VARCHAR(100)
        SELECT @rtidXml = CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),@ReplyMessageXml.query('/SCPReplyMessage/ReaderTypeID'))
        DECLARE @st NVARCHAR(max)
        SET @st = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),@tranXml)
        SET @st = REPLACE(@st,'</tran>',@rtidXml + '</tran>')
        SET @tranXml.modify('delete /SCPReplyMessage/ReaderTypeID')

        RETURN CONVERT(xml, @st)
    END
```

Input @ReplyMessageXml:

```
<SCPReplyMessage>
  <ContDeviceID>5974</ContDeviceID>
  <LocalTime>2019-08-29T12:35:43</LocalTime>
  <Priority>false</Priority>
  <ReaderTypeID>5</ReaderTypeID>
  <Deferred>false</Deferred>
  <tran>
    <ser_num>147</ser_num>
    <time>1567096543</time>
    <source_type>9</source_type>
    <source_number>0</source_number>
    <tran_type>6</tran_type>
    <tran_code>13</tran_code>
    <sys>
      <error_code>4</error_code>
    </sys>
    <sys_comm>
      <current_primary_comm>123</current_primary_comm>
      <current_alternate_comm>4</current_alternate_comm>
    </sys_comm>
    <c_id>
      <format_number>4</format_number>
      <cardholder_id>123</cardholder_id>
      <floor_number>4</floor_number>
    </c_id>
    <oal>
      <nData>AAAAAA==</nData>
    </oal>
  </tran>
  <SCPId>99</SCPId>
  <ReplyType>7</ReplyType>
  <ChannelNo>-1</ChannelNo>
</SCPReplyMessage>
```

output (which is correct):

```
<tran>
  <source_type>9</source_type>
  <source_number>0</source_number>
  <tran_type>6</tran_type>
  <tran_code>13</tran_code>
  <c_id>
    <format_number>4</format_number>
    <cardholder_id>123</cardholder_id>
    <floor_number>4</floor_number>
  </c_id>
  <oal>
    <nData>AAAAAA==</nData>
  </oal>
  <ReaderTypeID>5</ReaderTypeID>
</tran>
```

FINAL RESULT:
Thanks to @PeterHe

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_mTranAddl (@ReplyMessageXml XML)
returns XML
AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @tranXml XML
        SELECT @tranXml = @ReplyMessageXml.query('/SCPReplyMessage/tran')

        -- Discard extraneous tran elements
        SET @tranXml.modify('delete /tran/ser_num')
        SET @tranXml.modify('delete /tran/time')
        SET @tranXml.modify('delete /tran/sys')
        SET @tranXml.modify('delete /tran/sys_comm')

        -- move ReaderTypeID from outside <tran> to be inside <tran>
        DECLARE @x1 xml;
        SELECT @x1=@ReplyMessageXml.query('SCPReplyMessage/ReaderTypeID');
        SET @tranXml.modify('insert sql:variable("@x1") into (/tran)[1]')
        SET @tranXml.modify('delete /SCPReplyMessage/ReaderTypeID')

        RETURN @tranXml
    END
GO
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YOu can do it using xquery:

```
DECLARE @x xml = '<SCPReplyMessage>
  <ContDeviceID>5974</ContDeviceID>
  <LocalTime>2019-08-29T12:35:43</LocalTime>
  <Priority>false</Priority>
  <ReaderTypeID>5</ReaderTypeID>
  <Deferred>false</Deferred>
  <tran>
    <ser_num>147</ser_num>
    <time>1567096543</time>
    <source_type>9</source_type>
    <source_number>0</source_number>
    <tran_type>6</tran_type>
    <tran_code>13</tran_code>
    <sys>
      <error_code>4</error_code>
    </sys>
    <sys_comm>
      <current_primary_comm>123</current_primary_comm>
      <current_alternate_comm>4</current_alternate_comm>
    </sys_comm>
    <c_id>
      <format_number>4</format_number>
      <cardholder_id>123</cardholder_id>
      <floor_number>4</floor_number>
    </c_id>
    <oal>
      <nData>AAAAAA==</nData>
    </oal>
  </tran>
  <SCPId>99</SCPId>
  <ReplyType>7</ReplyType>
  <ChannelNo>-1</ChannelNo>
</SCPReplyMessage>'

DECLARE @output xml;
SELECT @output = @x.query('/SCPReplyMessage/tran');

SET @Output.modify('delete(/tran/ser_num)');
SET @Output.modify('delete(/tran/time)');
SET @Output.modify('delete(/tran/sys)');
SET @Output.modify('delete(/tran/sys_comm)');

DECLARE @x1 xml;
SELECT @x1=@x.query('SCPReplyMessage/ReaderTypeID');

SET @output.modify('insert sql:variable("@x1") into (/tran)[1]')
SELECT @output;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks.   I'm trying to move <ReaderTypeID>5</ReaderTypeID> from under <SCPReplyMessage> to be under <SCPReplyMessage><tran>

Answer (score 1):

Here is a much easier way by using XQuery FLWOR expression. The main idea is to construct what you need in one single statement instead of moving, deleting, inserting, etc.

> SQL

```
DECLARE @xml XML = 
N'<SCPReplyMessage>
  <ContDeviceID>5974</ContDeviceID>
  <LocalTime>2019-08-29T12:35:43</LocalTime>
  <Priority>false</Priority>
  <ReaderTypeID>5</ReaderTypeID>
  <Deferred>false</Deferred>
  <tran>
    <ser_num>147</ser_num>
    <time>1567096543</time>
    <source_type>9</source_type>
    <source_number>0</source_number>
    <tran_type>6</tran_type>
    <tran_code>13</tran_code>
    <sys>
      <error_code>4</error_code>
    </sys>
    <sys_comm>
      <current_primary_comm>123</current_primary_comm>
      <current_alternate_comm>4</current_alternate_comm>
    </sys_comm>
    <c_id>
      <format_number>4</format_number>
      <cardholder_id>123</cardholder_id>
      <floor_number>4</floor_number>
    </c_id>
    <oal>
      <nData>AAAAAA==</nData>
    </oal>
  </tran>
  <SCPId>99</SCPId>
  <ReplyType>7</ReplyType>
  <ChannelNo>-1</ChannelNo>
</SCPReplyMessage>';

SELECT @xml.query('<tran>{
for $x in /SCPReplyMessage/tran
return ($x/source_type,
    $x/source_number,
    $x/tran_type,
    $x/tran_code,
    $x/c_id,
    $x/oal,
    $x/../ReaderTypeID)
}</tran>');
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks useful, but I do not always know what will be included in <tran>.  Still, as I learn more about XQuery, the FLWOR method of assembly will be useful at other times.